# Why does local-key-binding return a 1 for a key with no local binding

Tags: elisp, key-bindings, keymap

When I evaluate `(local-key-binding key)` for any arbitrary key that ***does not have a local binding***, I expect a return value of `nil`, but I almost always get a `1`.  If the key actually does have a local binding (say from a major mode) in the current buffer, then `local-key-binding` behaves as expected and returns the function to which the key is bound.

My question then, is **why does `local-key-binding` often return `1` when there is in fact no local binding for the given key?**

As an example, after opening emacs with `emacs -Q`, type

```
(key-binding (kbd "C-h h"))
(local-key-binding (kbd "C-h h"))
```

in the scratch buffer and evaluate each of the forms. Notice that `key-binding` returns `view-hello-file`, and `local-key-binding` return `1`.  The binding for `C-h h` is defined globally, not locally, so I expect `local-key-binding` to return `nil`.  Now try

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-h h") 'describe-bindings)
(key-binding (kbd "C-h h"))
(local-key-binding (kbd "C-h h"))
```

and evaluate each of the forms.  Notice that both `key-binding` and `local-key-binding` return `describe-bindings`.  Now try

```
(local-unset-key (kbd "C-h h"))
(key-binding (kbd "C-h h"))
(local-key-binding (kbd "C-h h"))
```

and evaluate each of the forms.  Notice that `key-binding` has gone back to `view-hello-file`, and `local-key-binding` now shows `nil`.

Comment: *Please provide an example* that fits your criterion and produces the result you are not expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`local-key-binding` uses `lookup-key` whose doc-string contains this:

> A number as value means KEY is "too long";
>   that is, characters or symbols in it except for the last one
>   fail to be a valid sequence of prefix characters in KEYMAP.
>   The number is how many characters at the front of KEY
>   it takes to reach a non-prefix key.

`local-unset-key` does not reverse the effect of `local-key-binding`, because it does not actually do what its doc-string claims it does:

> Remove local binding of KEY

But what actually happens boils down to:

```
(define-key (current-local-map) "\C-hh" nil)
```

(One could argue that it does what the doc-string claims, but it certainly doesn't do what one would expect when first reading that doc-string).

The keymap went through these stages:

```
(keymap)
(keymap (8 keymap (104 . describe-bindings))))
(keymap (8 keymap (104)))
```

To **remove** the binding for a key instead of re-binding it to `nil` you can use [`kmu-remove-key`](https://github.com/tarsius/keymap-utils/blob/master/keymap-utils.el#L372) from my library [keymap-utils](https://github.com/tarsius/keymap-utils).

When a key is bound to `nil` in a local keymap that prevents key lookup to consider the binding in the parent keymap, but it does not override the global binding.

Comment: So why does `local-unset-key` seem to "fix" the problem?  Isn't `KEY` still "too long" for `KEYMAP`?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the edit.  I think that clears things up somewhat.  So when `local-key-binding` returns a number, it is not a bug, but a feature. Is that what I am learning?  It seems like a strange feature.  If the key is not bound in the local map, why would you ever want the function to return anything but `nil`?

Comment: Well returning nil or an integer tells you "how much" the key is unbound. `nil` means `C-h h` is unbound (i.e. there is no entry for `C-h h`) and so is `C-h`, while `1` means `C-h h` is unbound but `C-h` is bound. It's unfortunate that `nil` can also mean `C-h h` is bound - to `nil`.

Comment: Are there other functions out there that are actually using this information?  It still seems weird to return a value that means "That key isn't bound, but it is *really close* to being bound."

Comment: I don't know. But I assume there is a reason for this :-)